# Should we add a yellow-paper tag?

Tags: discussion

I'm seeing review requests for a tag [yellow-paper](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yellow-paper) (YP).  Quite a few answers reference the YP, but much fewer questions reference the YP.  I checked Bitcoin SE and there is only 1 question with [whitepaper](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whitepaper).

I'm not sure if we should add [yellow-paper](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yellow-paper).  Some related tags to [yellow-paper](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yellow-paper) are [evm](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evm), [blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blockchain), [protocol](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protocol), [consensus](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consensus).

What should we do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add it, seems to be helpful when discussing the inner specs. Especially helpful for reverse lookup of parts of the yellow paper that trigger a lot of questions.

Comment: I agree with this.